# Problem on sign charts

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Today I stumbled upon a question involving sign charts. The question goes something like this:
Determine the sign chart of the function given by:
$$f(x,y) > \frac{x+y}{\ln(x^2+(y+1)^2-3)} $$

Now, I tried searching over the internet for this particular question as I have not encountered questions on sign charts involving two variables.

I am aware of methods to solve sign charts problems involving two variables. But I am totally lost on this particular one. Any help or tip-offs would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of dividing up the real line to show where your function is positive/negative, you now need to divide up $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: You mean $f(x,y)=...$, don't you?

Comment: @RobertZ I thought the same but i am not sure if there is some typo in the question statement or whether it was intended to be $< $

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Draw in the cartesian plane the following curves $x+y=0$, $x^2+(y+1)^2=3$ and $x^2+(y+1)^2=4$. These curves divide the plane in several regions. Try to determine for each region if the function
$$ \frac{x+y}{\ln(x^2+(y+1)^2-3)}$$
is well defined there, and, in case, its sign.

Recall that $\ln(t)$ is defined for $t>0$, it is negative in $(0,1)$, it is zero for $t=1$ and it is positive for $t>1$.

Comment: ok. I see what you are trying to say. I am a bit lost on the inclusion of $ln$ in the question. How to handle that? If it would have just been the quadratic equation in denominator i think it would have been easy

Comment: Recall that $\ln(t)$ is defined for $t>0$, it is negative in $(0,1)$, it is zero for $t=1$ and positive for $t>1$.

Comment: I mean $f(x,y) >....$ only. I also thought that it should have been $f(x,y) = .....$ but this is what the question contains

Comment: It was in one of the preparation CD's for GRE

Comment: And one more thing any reason for plotting $x^2 + (y+1)^2 = 4$ along with $x^2 + (y+1)^2 = 3$ ?

Comment: For $x^2 + (y+1)^2 = 4$, the argument of the logarithm is $1$ an therefore the denominator is zero. $x^2 + (y+1)^2 = 3$ the the argument of the logarithm is zero.

Comment: @Abhishek Tyagi preparation CD's for GRE? Any weblink to the pdf?

Comment: No I don't have any weblink or pdf